# Parsing a regex

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, regex

I am having trouble writing a regular expression in C#; its purpose is to extract all words that start with '@' from a given string so they can be stored in some type of data structure.

If the string is "The quick @brown fox jumps over the lazy @dog", I'd like to get an array that contains two elements: brown and dog. It needs to handle the edge cases properly.  For example, if it's @@brown, it should still produce 'brown' not '@brown'.

Comment: word will be any alphanumeric string with no spaces.

Comment: @Prabhu: yes, but are `niño`, `éléphant` or `Marie-Hélène` words ?

Comment: Is an alphanumeric string meaning one that contains nothing but `\p{Alphabetic}` and/or `\p{Number}` code points in it?  Or did you have some more restricted meaning that you wished to impose?

Comment: @M42, a word can be: @"^([A-Za-z0-9])*"

Comment: If they are words, then you cannot use `\w`.  You must use the true `\p{Alphabetic}` property with additional stipulations.

Comment: Ah, a 1960’s-style word, not one from this century. But the broken old `\w` is still not what you want.  If you don’t want any words words other  that what you have written, then why not use that? BTW, I think you do not want `*`, since that matches nothing.

Comment: @tchrist Yes :-) Actually it's for usernames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this

C#:

```
string quick = "The quick @brown fox jumps over the lazy @dog @@dog";
MatchCollection results = Regex.Matches(quick, "@\\w+");

foreach (Match m in results)
{
    Literal1.Text += m.Value.Replace("@", "");
}
```

takes care of your edge case too. (@@dog => dog)

Comment: Does `\w` in C♯ meet [The Unicode Standard’s requirement](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties) that `\w` **must match exactly** `[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Mark}\p{Connector_Punctuation}]`? If so, it matches both more and less than the original request.  If it it does not, then it surely matches far less than the original request specified.

Comment: `\w` matches ` [\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}]`, whilst (natch!) `\W` matches its negation and `\b` (word boundary) matches a zero-width (^|$|\W).

Comment: Matches: Lowercase, Uppercase, Titlecase, Other, Modifier, Number/Decimal Digit, Punctuation Connector (such as `_`)
[Word Character: \w - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=VS.90).aspx#WordCharacter)

Comment: @Nicholas: So they still haven’t made it match what Unicode says it must.  That’s too bad. It is missing the `\p{Other_Alphabetic}` characters, which includes various `\p{GC=Mark}`, `\p{GC=Letter_Number}`, and `\p{GC=Symbol}` code points.  Check the spec.

Comment: @mdmullinax: But I thought Nicholas said it matched `\p{GC=Ll}` and `\p{GC=Lu}` and such.  Those are quite different from the real Unicode `\p{Lowercase}` and `\p{Uppercase}` properties, which are defined quite differently from the far more restricted case that you are talking about. `Lowercase` and `Lowercase_Letter` are **VERY DIFFERENT**. Java had screwed this up royally all the way until JDK7. Is C# similarly broken?

Comment: @tchrist, the Unicode categories for `\w` in `C#` are `Ll, Lu, Lt, Lm, Lo, Lm, Nd, Pc`, there's also an option in .NET to use ECMAScript compliance so `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` using that option

Comment: @mdmullinax:  You’re saying that C# chooses to disregard [what the Unicode Standard in RL1.2a of UTS#18 says  that `\w` must match?](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties) How do you write a standards-comforming application then? Does C# even bother to make such required properties as `Alphabetic`, `Uppercase`, or `Lowercase` available?  Those 3 are among the 11 properties **absolutely required** by [UTS#18’s RL1.2](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Categories) for basic Unicode work. Does C# really still not even meet these most basic of level 1 requirements?

Comment: I can't say I've ever cracked open the regular expression code via Reflector to look. I just looked at MSDN (which might well be incorrect). As of CLR v4.0, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx sez \w matches any of Ll,Lu,Lt,Lo,Lm,Nd,Pu. If you want to be safe, don't depend on implementation: explicitly define your character classes and you won't be surprised...except from faulty code.

Comment: @Nicholas: You can’t define a character class that isn’t available. You need the `Alphabetic` property just for starters.

Comment: @tchrist: Whatever. This appears to be an issue that pushes your buttons (http://www.google.com/search?q=alphabetic+Letter+tchrist+site%3Astackoverflow.com). Enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

`@[\w\d]+` should work for you.

Tested using http://www.regextester.com/.

This works by matching for the `@`, followed by one or more word characters.  The `\w` represents any "word character" [(character sets)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), the `\d` represents any digit, and the `+` [(repetition)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) indicates one or more.  The `\w` and `\d` are both allowed by being wrapped in brackets.

To exclude the `@` you could use `str.Substring(1)` to ignore the first character, or use the regex `@([\w\d]+)` and extract the first group.

Comment: I do not believe there exists **any** definition of `\w` that maps to alphanumeric strings.  Neither the stupid and useless old ASCII definition that some regex libraries are still 20 years out of date with, nor the current version required by [The Unicode Standard](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties) maps exactly to `[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Number}]`.

Comment: @tchrist He hadn't specified alpha-numeric when I posted.

Comment: @tchrist The tester does map it that way.

Comment: Ah, I see.  That makes sense then. English is generally far less precise than our regexes demand.

Comment: Whether maps it that way or not is immaterial.  What matters is whether or not it is compliant with [The Unicode Standard](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties).  It seems that it is not a conforming application.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your definition of "word" (`\w` is more the C-language definition of a symbol valid in an identifier or keyword: `[a-z0-9_]`.), you might try the folowing — I'm defining "word" here as a sequence of non-whitespace characters:

```
(^|\s)(@+(?<atword>[^\s]+))(\s|$)
```

The above has been tested [here](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx), and matches the following:

- Match start-of-string or a whitespace character, followed by
- 1 or more `@` characters, followed by
- 1 or more non-whitespace characters, in group named 'atword', followed by
- a whitespace character or end-of-string.

For successful matches, the named group `atword` will contain the text following the lead-in `@` sign(s).

So:

- `This @@ foo` won't match.
- `This @foo bar` will match
- `@@@foobarbat is kind of silly will match
- `@@@foobar@bazabat will match.
- `silly.@rabbit, tricks are for kids` won't match, but
- `silly @rabbit, tricks are for kids` will match and you'll get `rabbit,` rather than `rabbit` (like I said, you need to think about how you define 'word'.
- etc.